# CellStyle is applied only upon editing cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using this sample to change the color of a particular cell in the file

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\vineet.xlsx");
//InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");


Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();

XSSFCellStyle defaultStyle = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.getCellStyleAt((short) 0);

style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
//style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
if (cell == null)
  cell = row.createCell(3);
cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
cell.setCellValue("a test");

if (cell.getCellStyle().equals(defaultStyle)) {
  cell.setCellStyle(style);
}
// Write the output to a file
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\vineet.xlsx");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

at the first glance there are no changes, but when i try to edit the cell value using excel then the cell became yellow-backgrounded.

Answer (score 0):

you already got the needed line to do what you need but you commented it out.

```
//style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

and change this:

```
style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
```

to

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
```

Comment: This will result in a cell with black foreground

Comment: @test11 not sure if i understand foreground and background correctly, but try my answer now